# Node.js Command Prompt

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to learn Node.js. I really like a lot of the ideas I've seen. Currently, I have "Hello, World" working. To run hello world, I simply type `node hello.js` from a windows command prompt. Now, I'm trying to integrate Node in with Visual Studio as a Tool. Essentially, I want to be able to click the "TOOLS" menu in Visual Studio and choose "Node", and my currently selected file will run in a Node environment.

My question is, how do I do this? Currently, I have the following external tool configured:

```
Title: &Node
Command: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
Arguments: node $(ItemFileName)
Initial Directory: $(ItemDir)
```

When I choose "Node" from the "TOOLS" menu, a command prompt window is opened. The directory is set to the directory of the file I've chosen. However, the command "node [filename]" doesn't get executed or entered. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I replicated the issue you've experienced so I've tried to simply point it to `node.exe` instead and seems to work pretty well ;)) Will probably end up using this as well!

[image: output]